# uimenu buttons remain pressed and trigger also other menus by just sliding over them: pushbutton behaviour desired

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, matlab-uitable

I implemented various `uimenu`s in my `uitable` but there appears a very annoying behaviour.

```
function createUItable

    h = figure
    ...

    uimenu(h,'Label','MenuButton','Callback',@someAction)

end
%---------
function someAction(~,~)
    %some action
end
```

But after executing the callback function, the menu button remains pressed and highlighted and not even that, when I slide over the next menu button, this one is triggered also!

[This behaviour was also described at Matlab Central, but without solution.](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/65223)

I tried the suggested:

```
function someAction(~,~)
    %some action
    set(gcbo,'Enable','off')
    drawnow
    set(gcbo,'Enable','on')
end
```

which does not change anything. `set(gcbo,'Enable','off')` alone would solve the sliding problem, but also disables the whole button, what I don't want.
I also tried to use the ['Checked','Visible' and 'Interuptible' property](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/uimenu_props.html) without success.
This problem must be known, any hints?

I also thought about using `uicontrol` instead of `uimenu` and use a pushbutton, but I don't get it work.

---

Edit: when I put my menubutton into a submenu it works perfect:

```
button = uimenu(h,'Label','MenuButton');
uimenu(button,'Label','MenuButton','Callback',@someAction)
```

---

Edit2:
A `pushbutton` works also, but how could I place it into the menubar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess MATLAB implementation is this way, because setting a callback at the top-level menu is very odd.
Naturally in GUI's (not only MATLAB), when you click the top-level menu (like "File", "Edit", etc.) the standard behaviour is, that a submenu pops open rather than an immediate action being executed.
So you should only use the top-level callback to e.g. dynamically create/modify the associated submenus.

I think there are two alternatives to go:

1) If you'd like to stick to that manner (one, always-visible button-like element), then you should rather use the toolbar via a `uipushtool`:

```
hToolbar = uitoolbar(parentFigure);
uipushtool(hToolbar, 'ClickedCallback', @someAction);
```

This does not have the `'Label'` property though, so you'll have to work with `'CData'` and may be a `'TooltipString'`.

2) Create a top-level menu that contains your actual action-menu:

```
topMenu = uimenu(parent, 'Label', 'Actions');
uimenu(topMenu, 'Label', 'MenuButton', 'callback', @someAction)
```

From the general point of view on GUI design, both alternatives have the benefit of being the more commonly used style, thus being more intuitive to any user.

Comment: that is a very nice compromise!

Comment: which one? just out of curiosity ;)

Comment: well number 2) I already mentioned in my question, so it was not new. But 1) is nice, just have to find some nice icons

Answer (score 1):

I found an interesting work-around for this problem while keeping the callback in the TOP menu.  Turns out that using the uistack function released focus from the menu item so in the top-level menu callback, I placed

```
uistack(hObj,'down'); 
uistack(hObj,'up'); 
drawnow;
```

Which does nothing to the actual ordering but releases the menu items' focus.